# Filter all values which are greater than the first value in group

Tags: sql

I have a data table that looks like this

```
GROUP    VALUE 
A        46    
A        50    
A        39    
B        14    
B        9     
B        65
```

I want to write a query that returns the following table.

```
GROUP    VALUE 
A        50    
B        65
```

That is, only the rows where the VALUE is greater than the VALUE in the first row in group.

Thanks!

Comment: (1) you need a column that defines the ordering of the rows (2) which database are you using: mysql, oracle, sql-server...?

Answer (score 1):

You can use `row_number()`

```
select
    group,
    value
from
(
    select
        *,
        row_number() over (partition by group order by value) as rn
    from data
) subq
where rn = 2
```

Answer (score 1):

For your question to make sense at all, you need a column that defines the ordering of rows within each group (otherwise, there is no such thing as the *first* rows in a group).

Assuming that you have such a column, say called `id`, then one option is to use window function `first_value()`:

```
select *
from (
    select t.*, first_value(value) over(partition by group order by id) first_val
    from mytable t
) t
where value > first_val
```